# Trying to make a python code for connecting to a wifi network in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, netsh

I'm coming from Linux and I don't understand why I can't connect from the command line, what I'm doing wrong ? I'm always getting the "no profile" error.

ty for the help:

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAQw5.png)

[The error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWvZ7.png)

Comment: why not just put your code in your post? You can specify a code block by indenting every line with 4 spaces...

Comment: That does not seem to be a python problem: [https://superuser.com/questions/370508/connecting-to-wireless-network-via-command-prompt-in-windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/370508/connecting-to-wireless-network-via-command-prompt-in-windows-7)